# How to theme the separate page for editing profiles provided by Profile2

Tags: theming, users

I'm using D7.
I'd like to theme the separate page for editing profiles provided by Profile2 module(whose URL is **MYWEBSITE.com/profile-MYPROFILE/[uid]/edit**).
I searched and found the way that somebody has already suggested. And, by reference to that, I tried the way below. But it doesn't work. Can anybody tell me where I made a mistake?

Here is the way I tried but that didn't work...

**1st: Create the customthem_theme() below into  template.php file of customtheme theme.**

```
function customtheme_theme() {    
    $items = array();
    $items['user_profile_form'] = array(
        'render element' => 'form',
        'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'customtheme') . '/templates',
        'template' => 'user-profile-form',
        'preprocess functions' => array(
             'customtheme_preprocess_user_profile_form'
        ),
    );
    return $items;
}
```

**2nd:  Create the template file user-profile-form.tpl.php and place it in the templates folder of custometheme.**

**3rd: Code the fields I want to display on user-profile-form.tpl.php**

for ex

```
<html>
<?php

print drupal_render($form['form_build_id']);
print drupal_render($form['form_id']);
?>

<div>
         <?php  print render($form['profile_MYPROFILE']['field_MYFIELD']); ?>
</div>
</html>
```

I'm still very new to drupal and, honestly, don't figure out how its system works yet. I'm sorry if this is a very easy mistake to you. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change where it says `customtheme` to the actual theme name you are using.

for example if you are using bartik:

```
function bartik_theme() {
'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'bartik') . '/templates',
'preprocess functions' => array(
         'bartik_preprocess_user_profile_form'
    ),
```

The files should be located in your theme folder.

Comment: Thank you for answering, Akko.
Actually, I tried the way you suggested on.
I coded it after 
 [return _zen_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path);] 
within function_zen_theme(). But it didn't work. Do you know where I made mistake?

Comment: Can you show me the code of your comeplete theme function please? Then it's easier to see where you went wrong.